# License for donating software to not for profit - non exclusive

Tags: license-recommendation, law

I am doing some voluntary programming work for a not for profit - and it will be far faster if I re-use several thousand lines of boilerplate code I have previously written for commercial projects owned by me.

I want to provide free, in perpetuity and non-exclusive rights to use the software - but I do not want them to have the ability to sell it or share to third parties or in anyway prevent my continued use of the code. I thus want to give limited permission to use - but retain copyright and permission to publish the code to myself.

Does anyone know of an 'off the shelf' or example License that would be suitable or at lease close to this need?

ps. I know the license I am seeking is not 'open source' - but I posted this question over at Software Engineering and they said it was in scope here but not there..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about open source software. The folks at Software Engineering should not have sent you here, sorry about that.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not. Basically you need to consult your lawyer and write a contract and proprietary license. It's the standard case for proprietary license.